# crc32 function of zlib fails in swift 3 Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<Bytef>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer)'

Tags: swift, zlib

I want to make a CRC32 Hash out of a string and so I got the zlib function crc32.

But in Swift 3 this makes problems.

The code looks like this:

```
func crc32HashString(_ string: String) {
    let strData = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let crc = crc32(uLong(0), UnsafePointer<Bytef>(strData!.bytes), uInt(strData!.length))
}
```

The compiler gives me this Error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<Bytef>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer)'
```

How do I resolve this error?

best regards and thank you for your help!

Artur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bytes of a `Data` value are accessed using the

```
/// Access the bytes in the data.
///
/// - warning: The byte pointer argument should not be stored and used outside of the lifetime of the call to the closure.
public func withUnsafeBytes<ResultType, ContentType>(_ body: (UnsafePointer<ContentType>) throws -> ResultType) rethrows -> ResultType
```

method. It calls a closure with a (typed) pointer to the bytes:

```
let strData = string.data(using: .utf8)! // Conversion to UTF-8 cannot fail
let crc = strData.withUnsafeBytes { crc32(0, $0, numericCast(strData.count)) }
```

Here the type of `$0` is automatically inferred as 
`UnsafePointer<Bytef>` from the context.

**Update:** As of **Swift 5,**

```
public func withUnsafeBytes<ResultType>(_ body: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> ResultType) rethrows -> ResultType
```

calls the closure with a “raw” buffer pointer which must be “bound” to the expected type `Bytef` (aka `UInt8`):

```
let strData = string.data(using: .utf8)! // Conversion to UTF-8 cannot fail
let crc = strData.withUnsafeBytes {
    crc32(0, $0.bindMemory(to: Bytef.self).baseAddress, numericCast(strData.count))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast Answer!

Comment: Great answer Martin.  Quick question: why do you use `numericCast` here instead of just `strData.count`?  Is this used to prevent overflow?

Comment: @JAL: `strData.count` is an `Int`, but `crc32()` takes an `uInt` parameter. So you have to convert the value, either as `uInt(strData.count)`, or with that generic function `numericCast` which converts between arbitrary signed and unsigned integer types. It is a matter of taste which one you choose.

Comment: Up! Unfortunately this solution seems outdated for Swift 5. $0 produces error `Cannot convert value of type UnsafeRawBufferPointer to expected argument type UnsafePointer<Bytef>? (aka Optional<UnsafePointer<UInt8>>)`. Also tried $0.baseAdress that returns UnsafeRawPointer but `Cannot convert value of type UnsafeRawPointer? to expected argument type UnsafePointer<Bytef>?(aka Optional<UnsafePointer<UInt8>>)`